# Difference of two Dates in Computed Field

Tags: datetime, entities

fields: (Date to - Date from) = Total Number of Days

How can I compute the total number of days between two dates using Computed Field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample snippet (to be used in Computed Code PHP Block inside of a computed field)

```
$food_date_value = array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_food_date'));
$food_date = new DateObject($food_date_value['value'], '');
$current_date = new DateObject('now', '', 'm/d/Y');
$entity_field[0]['value'] =$food_date->difference($current_date, 'days');
```

field_food_date is a date in the Unix Timestamp format (another field in my content type). DateObject can then be used for doing any date calculations.

Comment: Thanks!
but what if the date is not the current date?
I also use a pop calendar.

Comment: You can feed in the other date similar to how $food_date is constructed

Comment: Here is my code and it's not working :( 
`$start_date = array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_date_from')); $end_date = array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_date_to'));) $start_date = new DateObject($start_date['value'], ''); $end_date = new DateObject($end_date['value'], ''); $entity_field[0]['value'] =$start_date->difference($end_date, 'days');`

Comment: What format are your field_date_from and fielddate_to ? They have to be Unix timestamp based or an array consisting of the keys "year", "date", "month"

Comment: Hurrray! I did it. I solved the error. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you add additional codes wherein the weekends and holidays will not be counted? I have tried many codes but they are not working. Thank you!

Comment: You can get the "Day of the week" using the "w" or "N" format to get the starting and ending day of week. If they are greater than 5, then you know there is a weekend in between them. Calculate the week number as well so that if the difference is more than a week, you can subtract that number of weekend days from it. I am not in front of a computer, but this should be easy to do. Holidays Ive no idea since I dont know how to calculate holidays for a year.

Answer (score 0):

If the Machine name of your date-field is 'field_example_date', then the **Computed Code (PHP)** would be

```
$startdate = $entity->field_example_date['und'][0]['value']; // Value of start-date
$enddate = $entity->field_example_date['und'][0]['value2']; // Value of end-date

$datediff = strtotime($enddate) - strtotime($startdate);
/* The PHP Function STRTOTIME parses the english textual datetime description
 * into a Unix timestamp
 */

$num_leaves = $datediff/(60*60*24);
/* Since we need the number of days IN-BETWEEN, 
 * we divide the resultant difference by 60*60*24 . 
 *
 * Incase of counting no.of days "FROM" to "TO" days, add 1 to the above result.
 * $num_leaves = $datediff/(60*60*24) + 1;
 */

 $entity_field[0]['value'] = $num_leaves;
```

The **Display Code (PHP)** will have

```
$display_output = $entity_field_item['value'];
```